# Rich iPad application using motion charts with flexible playback capabilities

Tags: data-visualization, qlikview

What charting tool is the most promising to develop a rich iPad application that can display motion charts with replay capabilities? The end-user should be able to change what are being plotted on the x- and y- axes.

In addition, can such applications be built using QlikView, or Tableau to handle the charting?
Do I use the API for that?
Also, how about FusionCharts?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau can do this for you out of the box, and building the chart itself is trivial.

The basic steps you'd follow to accomplish this are:

- Download Tableau Desktop Create your viz using the tool - for
  "replay" functionality, drop a database field like "Date" on
  Tableau's "Pages" shelf.
- Publish the completed viz to Tableau Server
- On the iPad, point Safari at the viz as hosted on Tableau Server, or
  download the free Tableau app and do the same thing.

The "catch" here, if you want to call it that, is that Tableau Server is doing all the heavy lifting around rendering the viz for you - there is no app-side API or library you're leaning on - you're just using the mobile device as a viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is fairly similar for Qlikview also.

- Download the Qlikview Personal edition (free)
- Develop your required application
- Deploy the application to Qlikview Server (you will need a license for this)
- Access the application on the Qlikview server using Safari on the iPad

The same Qlikview application can be accessed via desktop PC's using either the IE Plugin or a browser with no installation using the Ajax client.

If you would like to see some demo applications, you can access them on your iPad at http://demo.qlikview.com/

Comment: You wrote: *Deploy the application to Qlikview Server (you will need a license for this)*. Do you know if there cheap way to test it localy?

Comment: If you contact QV you can probably get a time limited eval key for the server product. The IE Plugin looks pretty much identical to the desktop product. The Ajax plugin looks and behaves differently, although is vastly improved in Version 11 and now quite usable (V10 was not so great). You can get a feel for how the Ajax client will work using "Web View" in the desktop (View -> Turn On/Off Web View), although it will not be identical to how it renders on the server.  If you want to see server rendered applications in action - check out http://demo.qlikview.com/ and look at some of the samples.